# Checked event firing when grouping added to DataGrid - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, events, checkbox, datagrid

I'm having a problem where when adding grouping to my datagrid; the event I have defined as "Checkbox.Checked" gets called when it shouldn't be.
When this line of code is not commented out "`collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("_group"));`" the bug occurs.

Upon starting my application with this line in, the first check of any checkbox works as it should, then on the second click, if I click literally anywhere on the datagrid, the checked event will be fired.

Do any of you have any idea?

Thanks.

I have events define on my DataGrid like this;

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style>
         <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="Method_checked"/>
         <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="Method_Unchecked"/>
    </Style>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
```

I have since added grouping to my data using the following code in C#;

```
ListCollectionView collection = new ListCollectionView(listOfData);
collection.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("_group"));
dgData.ItemsSource = collection;
```

I have added groups to my datagrid adding the following code in xaml;

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
        <GroupStyle.Panel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.Panel>
    </GroupStyle>
```

You may noticed "GroupHeaderStyle" which is defined above;

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                     <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True"
                                  Background="White"
                                  Foreground="Black">
                         <Expander.Header>
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                         </Expander.Header>
                         <ItemsPresenter/>
                     </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking whether the box is actually checked in the event-fire method?

Comment: Yeah I have, it still classes it as "Checked" even though visually it's not.

Comment: What is the original source of event ?